# I want to build an node interactive CLI which would have autosuggestion of keyword. Please suggest me the list of packages

Tags: node.js

My node interactive CLI application would trigger certain APis based on the commands provided. The whole application should be interactive with the user auto suggesting set of keywords to be used to build the commands.

The auto suggestion should happen while writing commands in CMD or any 3rd party terminal used by the user.

I have tried building the application with gluegun. Packages used for auto suggestion are inquirer.js, omelette.js, prompt-autocompletion.js,cli-autocompletion.js. But no luck.

There are two scenarios:
1.) command keyword1 keywo
     keyword2
     keyword3
     keyword4

2.) command (press enter)
     key
     keyword1
     keyword2
     keyword3
     keyword4        //You can select one keyword and it will get filtered

Answer (score 0):

you can use `commander` js, which is good `library` for building `CLI` tools

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander